# Determinant of sub-matrices of a non-square Matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Consider $A_{n\times n}$ is an asymmetric matrix over a field. We denote the transpose of matrix $A$ with $A^T$. 
 Suppose that the matrix $A$ has 
this property that all 
it's  sub-matrices of order $i$, $1\leq i \leq n$, have non-zero determinant. We can see that because of $A$
has this property then all  sub-matrices  $A^T$ of order $i$, $1\leq i \leq n$ have non-zero determinant too.

Assume matrix $B_{n \times 2n}$ is constructed by the  matrices $A$ and $A^T$, in the following form
 $$
 B=[A|A^T]
$$
**My question**:
Is it true claim that all sub-matrices of order $j$, $1\leq j \leq n$, of the matrix  $B$  have non-zero determinant?

We know that for 
a sub-matrix of $B$ of order $i$, we can choose $i$ number of set $[1..n]$ for rows ,$n \choose i$,
 and $i$ number of set $[1..2n]$ for choosing columns, $2n \choose i$.

*For example:* consider the following form of the  companion  matrix ($n>2$)
$$
C_n=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 &1 &0 &\cdots &\cdots &0 \\
0 &0 &1 &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &0 \\
0 &\cdots &\cdots &0&0 &1 \\
1 &1 &1 &\cdots &1 &1
\end{array}
\right)_{n\times n}
$$
with numerical computation, I have seen that the $n\times (n-1)$ power of matrix $C_n$ has this property and all sub-matrices of matrix $B=[C_n^{n^2-n}|{(C_n^{n^2-n})}^T]$ have non-zero determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Take $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

Then 
$B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$.

Now take the second and third column to get a determinant of zero. :)

Comment: Thanks, you mean second and third columns!